# GKE Kubernetes RBAC bind default role to my limited custom

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, rbac

I'm using G
I want to create a custom user that have only access to specific namespace, I used this yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: develop-user
  namespace: develop

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: develop-user-full-access
  namespace: develop
rules:
- apiGroups: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  resources:
  - services
  verbs: ["get"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: develop-user-view
  namespace: develop
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: develop-user
  namespace: develop
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: develop-user-full-access
```

so I get a certificate and added to my kube config, after I switched context to this new service account and figured out that I still have access to everything :(
Why did it happen and how to fix?

my kubeconfig (pastebin copy: https://pastebin.com/s5Nd6Dnn):

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: %certificate-data%
    server: https://animeheaven.nyah
  name: anime-cluster-develop
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: anime-cluster-develop
    namespace: develop
    user: develop-user
  name: anime-develop
current-context: anime-develop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: develop-user
  user:
    client-key-data: %certdata%
    token: %tokenkey%
```

Comment: you want to give all permission of a namespace to this `develop-user`?  Or, some specific permission?

Comment: @MarufTuhin hey, good question, based on config I provided I want to give acess to developers to access only `develop` namespace and being able to run only `get` command in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://medium.com/uptime-99/making-sense-of-kubernetes-rbac-and-iam-roles-on-gke-914131b01922
https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-rbac-port-forward-4c7eb3951e28

these two articles helped me finally! I almost felt into depression because of this stupid stuff, thanks to uptime-99 and ManagedKube I did it! yay!

the key is to create kubernetes-viewer user in gcloud and then create a role for him
here is a hint!

```
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: develop
  name: allow-developer-port-forward
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/portforward"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: anime-developer-port-access
  namespace: develop
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: ANIMEDEVERLOP@gmail.com
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: allow-developer-port-forward
  apiGroup: ""
```

then

> kubectly apply -f accessconfig.yaml

thats it!
have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article on how to set it up: https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html.

In general, your configuration is fine, what I changed is the line `- apiGroups: rbac.authorization.k8s.io` changed to:

```
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
```

Then, applied the following steps:

1. Create `develop` namespace

```
$ kubectl create namespace develop
```

2. Create RBAC from your configuration.

```
$ kubectl apply -f rbac.yaml
```

3. Read Cluster IP, Token, and CA Certificate.

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
$ kubectl get secret develop-user-token-2wsnb -o jsonpath={.data.token} -n develop | base64 --decode
$ kubectl get secret develop-user-token-2wsnb -o "jsonpath={.data['ca\.crt']}" -n develop
```

4. Fill the `~/.kube/config` file (as described in the [linked guide](https://jeremievallee.com/2018/05/28/kubernetes-rbac-namespace-user.html))
5. Change the context to `develop`
6. The user have access only to checking services in the `develop` namespace.

```
$ kubectl get service my-service -n mynamespace
Error from server (Forbidden): services "my-service" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:develop:develop-user" cannot get services in the namespace "mynamespace"
$ kubectl get service my-service -n develop
hError from server (NotFound): services "my-service" not found
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, appreciate it, but I still can run `kubectl get pods --namespace prod ` and get access to other namespaces :\

Comment: btw, I used exact same article to setup my serviceaccount

Comment: It's weird, especially that I also checked it on GKE yesterday... Do you have the `develop` namespace in your context configuration in `~/.kube/config`? You could also add what you added into your `config` file in the question description. Maybe that could be some hint of what could be wrong.

Comment: hey, thanks for suggestion! But I had namespace specified in config, attached config to my question

Comment: I got a suggestion from another chat that it may be a default role binding that binds to every new user, but I don't know how to validate it